# Parsley Multistep Form Validation: mark tabs

Tags: typo3, parsley.js, powermail

In a multistep form using parsley.js (loaded by TYPO3 Powermail extension),  Tabs that contain required fields which habve not been filled, are not highlighted on submit. Which forces the user to look through all tabs before she can try the next submit.

Is there a way to tell parsley.js to give a class to fieldsets that contain „erroring“ fields? So those tabs can be highlighted?

Comment: A common way is to finish multistep-forms tab by tab, so that only finished tabs are left behind. So the "next" button is only shown when one step is fully ok. Is it in your form differently?

Comment: Yes, my form has the "continue" button shown all the time. I'm not sure if it's a good thing UX wise, but is there a setting in Parsley for that?

Comment: Do you know the example on this page? http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/multisteps.html